# Running a global test setup before each test in Jest

Tags: unit-testing, jestjs

I'm trying to have a test setup function executed before each single test in my Jest test suite. I know that I can use `beforeEach` to accomplish this within a single test file, but I want to do it globally for all my test files **without** having to explicitly modify each single file.

I looked into the [jest configuration file](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html), and noticed a couple of configs that thought could have worked: [`globalSetup`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#globalsetup-string) and [`setupFiles`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array), but they seem to be run only once (at the very beginning of the test run). Like I said, I need it to be run before "each" `it` block in my test files.

Is this possible?

Comment: I know this doesn't help at all, but I do not think there is a way to do this in Jest.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You could use `setupFilesAfterEnv` (which replaces `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile`, deprecated from jest version 24.x) which will run before each test

```
// package.json
{
  // ...
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/setupTests.js"]
  }
}
```

And in `setupTests.js`, you can directly write:

```
global.beforeEach(() => {
  ...
});

global.afterEach(() => {
   ...
});
```

Comment: Note: this works, but as @Alvin Lee pointed below: "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile is deprecated in favor of setupFilesAfterEnv"

Comment: Doesn't work for me... global.beforeEach is not a function.

Comment: @geoidesic use setupFilesAfterEnv instead of setupTests (as the name implies, the test env including beforeEach will be set up by then)

Comment: This does not work anymore. You have to add `setupFilesAfterEnv` into `jest.config.js`.

Comment: What does the `global` value do in the setupTests.js? Do I need to do a default export here as well?

Comment: My issue was making the rookie mistake of defining `setupFilesAfterEnv` twice and then having issues with the file not loading.

Answer (score 17):

Just as a follow-up to the answer from @zzz, the more recent [documentation on Configuring Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration) notes:

> Note: *`setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` is deprecated in favor of `setupFilesAfterEnv`.*

So now, your file should look like this:

```
// package.json
{
  // ...
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
    ]
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 16):

`setupFilesAfterEnv` configuration is the way to go, and yes you can use `beforeEach` in that file and it will run in every test across all the suit.

```
// jest.config.js

module.exports = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts']
}
```

```
// tests/setupTests.ts

beforeEach(() => {
  console.log('before each')
})

afterEach(() => {
  console.log('after each')
})
```

Try it out!