# How to run arbitrary code before each test re-run in watch mode in Jest?

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I need to run an arbitrary piece of code before each unit test re-run  in watch mode (to write a new hash or random generated number to the `test.json` file).

I had a problem when I was using `"setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"` which is mentioned in [Running a global test setup before each test in Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48722930/running-a-global-test-setup-before-each-test-in-jest)
in Jest configuration. It works, but it adds my script to test files and runs forever. Unfortunately I couldn't fix the problem, even when I use `"testPathIgnorePatterns"` or `"collectCoverageFrom"`.

Is there any better solution to this problem in Jest?